# How can I check the request which is in method?

Tags: php, request

My `test.php` code are bellow:

```
<?php

// First, include Requests
include('../library/Requests.php');

// Next, make sure Requests can load internal classes
Requests::register_autoloader();

function get_data(){
    // Now let's make a request!

    $params = array(
        "ws_tblclients_id" => 1232,
        "email" => "test22@cd.com",
        "username" => "asdas_asda",
        "phone" => "1518233776",
        "password" => "123456"
    );

    $request = Requests::post('http://demo:8000/api/users/register/', $params, null);

    // Check what we received
    echo "<pre>";

    var_dump($request);
    echo "</pre>";
}



if(isset($_GET['submit_get_data']) ){
    get_data();
}


?>

<form action="" method="post">
    <button name="submit_get_data" value="submit_get_data" type="submit">Click Me</button>
</form>
```

When I click the Click Me button, in the browser I only get the `post` action, which is the request PHP file itself.

My requirement is I want to check the `get_data`'s request. How can I test it?

Because when I click the <kbd>Click</kbd> button I get bellow error, but in the browser I can not to check the `get_data`'s request detail(http://demo:8000/api/users/register/):

```
{
    "body":"{"password":["This field must be filled。"],"phone":["This field must be filled"],"username":["This field must be filled"]}",
    "raw":"HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 118
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Allow: POST, OPTIONS
Vary: Accept, Cookie
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Wed, 05 Sep 2018 10:29:50 GMT
Connection: close

{"password":["This field must be filled"],"phone":["This field must 
be filled"],"username":["This field must be filled"]}",
    "headers":{

    },
    "status_code":400,
    "protocol_version":1.1,
    "success":false,
    "redirects":0,
    "url":"http://demo:8000/api/users/register/",
    "history":[

    ],
    "cookies":{

    }
}
```

So the request in the method we can not check in browser, but how can I check it in other way?

[image]

---

**EDIT-01**

I mean, in my `test.php`, there are two requests, one is click the Click Me button, which send a post request to self php file. the other is execute the `get_data()`  function, which is Requests' post. but in browser there only shows the previous one.

Comment: Hard to understand what you actually want to know here … If you send a form via POST, then you should probably not check for a _GET_ parameter afterwards here, `if(isset($_GET['submit_get_data']) ){` …?

Comment: @misorude See my edit-01, bro.

Comment: why do you need a function there? remove it. Or remove the if(isset from where you call the function: i can bet you never get inside

Comment: It's still pretty unclear what you want. You say that you see one request, but as far as I can see, there's no request bing made to `post.php` in the posted code at all? You've written that the code is in `test.php` and not `post.php`? Also, your form is using `method="post"` so `isset($_GET['submit_get_data'])` will always be false. There are too many question marks here. Please rewrite your question to clarify your issue.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I mean the `Requests::post ` there is a request.

Comment: Right now, your `get_data` function should not be called at all - because you check if `$_GET['submit_get_data']` is set, but your form is send with method POST. And if that particular API request is what you need to test - then why don’t you do this “stand alone”, why are you wrapping it into something that checks if something was send from a form in the first place? You are not even sending any specific values to use in the API call with your form, so what’s the point? Put this in a script that calls this API directly, call it in your browser normally via GET … and see what response you get.

Comment: @misorude Do you mean if a request in a parent request, it will not be list in the browser's network panel?

Comment: The browser’s network panel can only list requests made by your browser … Your second request is made by your PHP script, on the server side.